Use same name third party nuget package dll into same name project
I have Visual Studio class library project named "WCFExtras" where using same name third party nuget package called "WCFExtras" and it's installed properly. When build the application can see only class library application's dll but not third party nuget dll.
Is there any way I can use both dlls classes in consumer application?

It's a bad idea to use the same name. Consider using a prefix in the name that is your organization or product - e.g. MyOrg.WCFExtras. Is your class library wrapping and extending the third-party class library? Consider a name like WCFExtras.Extensions.

If you just want to use the 3rd library in the same name class library project, it is no problem.
But you can not make the two same-name assembly both exist in the same directory with completely compatibility.
But since you are able to control yourself project, there is one way to keep the project name:

Via this, you can make the two assemblies both exist, and at the same time, the project doesn't change:


Is there any way of merge for having third party dll's functionality should come as a part of my own project dll? so when make nuget of my project's and consume in another application can use all classes in one dll.

@Jeetu What do you mean, do you mean you don't want to change your project dll file name in configuration page, and want to merge the two same name dll(one is your  project dll, one is 3rd dll) to one dll? If yes, the answer is no, and don't do this, Currently there is no way to implement such a merge perfectly and stably, and you may encounter copyright issues if you do this in production.
